# Are there any HTML validators for either Opera, Firefox, Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I am looking for an HTML validator that is suitable for development mode, everything I have seen are merely hyper-links to w3c, which is no good when your URL is "localhost:3000".

So I am specifically looking for one that will validate the HTML within its own internal logic. Answers that contain plugins that link to external websites will be rewarded with a downvote.

Comment: I'm downvoting for your second paragraph - not the best approach to take when asking for help. The Web Developer toolbar for Firefox uses the W3C validator, and this works fine on local development sites - it submits the HTML itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be cheeky.

Write this PHP script:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("your source code here");
// if you get errors then your HTML is invalid.
// optionally, use libxml_use_internal_errors and libxml_get_errors
//     to handle errors and present a user-friendly response
```

You can now run this PHP script through your preferred method. Mine would be something like having `"your source code here"` being `file_get_contents("php://input")` and then passing the source code via STDIN, but whatever works for you.

Since it will be running on your local machine, you can even have it do `file_get_contents("http://localhost:3000")` to get your webpage :)